# there are other threads running in the session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, entity-framework

my controller code :

```
public ActionResult groupeditSubmit(List<string> barC, int PID = -1, int TID = -1, string DateT = "", int nPID = -1, int nTID = -1, string nDateT = "")
    {
            ViewBag.PID = new SelectList(db.Places, "ID", "Name", 0);
            ViewBag.TID = new SelectList(db.Transferees, "ID", "FullName", 0);
            ViewBag.DateT = DateT;
            var studentList = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update Barcode set PID = '"+nPID+ "' ,TID='"+nTID+ "' , DateT = '"+nDateT+ "' where (PID = "+PID+ " AND TID = "+TID+ " AND DateT = '"+ DateT + "' )");
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("groupedit");
    }
```

my view code :

```html
@model IEnumerable<barkod.Models.Barcode>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "groupedit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPanel.cshtml";
}
</form>
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <div class="row text-center">
        <form method="post" action="groupeditSubmit">
            <table class="table table-responsive">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        بارکد
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        مکان
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        تحویل گیرنده
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        تاریخ تحویل
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           <input name="barc" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.barC)" class="hidden" />
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.barC)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Place.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Transferee.FullName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateT)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("nTID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("nPID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.Editor("nDateT", new
           {
               htmlAttributes = new
               {
                   @class = "form-control"@*, Type = "date"*@,
                   required = "required",
                   @Value = ViewBag.DateT
               }
           })
                    @*<input type="button" id= "exampleI" class="btn-danger" value="#" name="Date" data-mddatetimepicker="true" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click" data-targetselector="#exampleI" required />*@
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group hidden">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("TID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group hidden">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("PID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group hidden">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.Editor("DateT", new
           {
               htmlAttributes = new
               {
                   @class = "form-control"@*, Type = "date"*@,
                   required = "required",
                   @Value = ViewBag.DateT
               }
           })
                    @*<input type="button" id= "exampleI" class="btn-danger" value="#" name="Date" data-mddatetimepicker="true" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click" data-targetselector="#exampleI" required />*@
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="ویرایش گروهی" />
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

it's ok in my localhost but when it runs in server, it gives me this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

Comment: *Please review the stack trace for more information*

Comment: How is db being scoped for the controller? Are you using an IoC container? Based on the details it looks like it's scoped as a Singleton or an instance that isn't scoped per request and re-issued so that concurrent requests would be served by the same DbContext instance.

Comment: @StevePy  My code is ok because its ok in my local host but when upload in server give error . I think its for iis config in server.no?

Comment: @GertArnold plz read up comment thx.

Comment: When you are running on localhost, are you running an IIS instance, or express/emulator? My point is that running on "my machine" is running a single instance, single session. If you upload it to an IIS instance that is responding to multiple requests, and 2 or more of those requests are handed the same DbContext instance you are going to have issues like this. You can trial a change to put your controller code in `using(var newdb = new MyDbContext()) { //.. }` with the code switched over to use newdb, which will narrow down if your original code is reusing a context.

Comment: I use Express version of iis @StevePy .using do well too in my pc but not well in server

Comment: @gilhamilton Please don't indent long strings when editing posts.

Comment: @mohammadmiraali Which comments? The exception message advises you to check the stack trace. You should do that first. We can't help you before you do that. If after that you still have no clue, you should add the stack trace to the question. In general: if an exception message contains such hints, follow up on them and show what you found by doing that.